# Show $\left(A \subseteq B \land \vert A \rvert = \lvert A \cup C \rvert\right) \implies \vert B \rvert = \lvert B \cup C \rvert$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that for any sets $A,B,C$:
$$\left(A \subseteq B \land \vert A \rvert = \lvert A \cup C \rvert\right) \implies \vert B \rvert = \lvert B \cup C \rvert$$
We have $A \subseteq B \implies \vert A \rvert \le \lvert B \rvert$, so $\vert A \cup C \rvert \le \lvert B \rvert$. Also, $B \subseteq (B \cup C) \implies \vert B \rvert \le \lvert B \cup C \rvert$, so it would suffice to show $\vert B \rvert \ge \lvert B \cup C \rvert$. This is where I get stuck. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I would try and figure out when $|A| = |A \cup C|$ rather than work with inequalities, personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|A| = |A \cup C|$, we know there is a one-to-one mapping between $A$ and $A \cup C$; let's say this is mapping $f$

We also know that $A \subseteq B$, so consider all the elements in $B-A$: these are exactly the same elements that are in $(B\cup C) - (A \cup C)$. So, define your one-to-one mapping $f'$ between $B$ and $B \cup C$ as follows:

For any $x \in A$: $f'(a) = f(a)$

For any $x \in B - A$: $f'(a) = a$

Comment: Does the lemma follow from the following facts? $\lvert X \cup Y \rvert = \lvert X \rvert +\lvert Y \rvert-\lvert X \cap Y \rvert$, so $\lvert X \cup Y \rvert = \lvert X \rvert$ gives $\lvert X \cap Y \rvert = \lvert Y \rvert$ and there cannot be a bijection between $Y$ and $X \cap Y$ unless $Y \subseteq X$?

Comment: @Zelazny That would work, sure!

Comment: @Zelazny  Oh hell!  I just realized I was thinking only of finite sets! For infinite sets, the Lemma doesn't even hold!  OK, let me redo my Answer. Hold on!

Comment: @Zelazny OK, I redid my answer!